# Android: How can I access fitness data from Mi Band 4?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to work with the number of steps collected directly from the band. I have tried using the native Bluetooth Low Energy methods (BluetoothGattCharacteristics etc) but I get a PERMISSION_DENIED when trying to access the data. I have also tried using the Google Fitness Sensors API but the Mi Band isn't listed as a DataSource for steps. Is there any way to get this data directly from the band to my app?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: No, I couldn't find anything sorry.

Comment: recently MI add google Fitness but its not solve our problem